# Change TableViewCell Text Color

Tags: ios7, uitableview

Here is a situation.
I have a TableCell with a Icon and a Label.
I want that when a PRESS the Cell, only my Label change Colors, without change the Background or anything, just the Text.
How I do that?

The effect is like the one on Spotify app.

[image: Spotify]

Comment: Why don't you change the foreground color of the label? Get the selected cell, find the label in the cell, change the foreground color.

Comment: @Suresh what do you mean with Foreground Color? The Regular color of text? how I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegate methods of the `UITableView` for this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell;
    // Initialize cell
    // If you want to use custom label, don't forget to set it a unique tag.
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Label";
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // If you created a custom label, get it like the next line and then change the color of it;
    // UILabel * label = (UILabel *) [selectedCell viewWithTag: UNIQUE_TAG];
    selectedCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Or which color you'd like.
}
```

Comment: This work only when I came back do the Label, not in the moment that I press the Label.

Comment: Can you try `tableView:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:` method instead `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` ?

Comment: Works but there is a problem. All Label change color. My TableCell has a Label with a `Outlet`, so in the `tableView:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:`I put self.myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];`
And when I use `UITableViewCell * selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`
    `selectedCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];` nothing happens.

Comment: If you don't set a string to `textLabel` property of the cell since it is not displayed, nothing should happen. If you have outlets, change their text colour.